# Why do Chat notifications show who the message is from, while comment notifications do not?

Tags: support, comments, chat, notifications, global-inbox

When someone leaves a comment to any of my posts, or employs `@Alex`, I get an inbox notification showing me the comment.

When someone responds to me in Chat I also get an inbox notification showing me the comment.

However, in the former case the notification shows the comment, including the `@Alex`, but without showing who left the comment; in the latter case, on the other hand, it shows me the comment, as well as who left the comment, but not the `@Alex`.

Is there a reason why the notification system is different for a post comments and Chat comments?

Here is a screenshot of my inbox where you can see the difference:

[image: Screenshot of inbox]

I don't particularly care that it's different; I am just wondering out of curiosity.

Answer (score 4):

Well, you don't see the username in the chat reply because the '@Alex' you see isn't part of the chat message; it's just rendered that way by the chat client. (I *think* that if you would change your username, it would change the mention to match your new username.)

If you get pinged out of the blue, your username *is* shown:

[image]

The comment in your example includes @Alex in its text, so it's shown verbatim in your inbox. There is no logic to strip it, because you can also be notified within a grammatically correct sentence, or with something like (cc @Alex).

It looks like notifications from the Q&A site *never* show who caused them. I don't know if this is a deliberate choice, but it nicely echoes the maxim 'the content itself is more important than who wrote it'. I agree that I sometimes (but not always) wish it *would* be shown.